# Flutter package Google_nav_bar - 3 tabs instead of 4

Tags: flutter, dart, navbar

I am making an app using Flutter and really like the package [google_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/google_nav_bar#-example-tab-) [(link to Github)](https://github.com/sooxt98/google_nav_bar). I got it installed and working but I can't figure out how to make the navbar 3 tabs instead of 4.

Here is my code:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Reviews',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Shop',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: Account',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Non existent',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Mijnmedicijn.nl'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(blurRadius: 20, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1))
        ]),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 8),
            child: GNav(
                gap: 8,
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 24,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
                tabs: [
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.home,
                    text: 'Home',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.heart_o,
                    text: 'Likes',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.search,
                    text: 'Account',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.user,
                    text: 'Profile',
                  ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                onTabChange: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = index;
                  });
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried deleting one of the Text("non existent") and last GButton but that did not work (it gives me a RangeError).

It is possible because on Github it shows an example with 3 tabs.

Is there anybody who would know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and removed the last Text() and last GButton() and it seems to work fine.

Here is the code I tried :

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Reviews',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Shop',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: Account',
      style: optionStyle,
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Mijnmedicijn.nl'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(blurRadius: 20, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1))
        ]),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 8),
            child: GNav(
                gap: 8,
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 24,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
                tabs: [
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.home,
                    text: 'Home',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.heart_o,
                    text: 'Likes',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.search,
                    text: 'Account',
                  )
                ],
                selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                onTabChange: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = index;
                  });
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: The code you made worked! I honestly don't know why mine did not work then (maybe I also deleted something else or something).